# ggplot2: ignoring nan values when plotting error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having a seemingly simple problem that for some reason I can'f find any information on.

I am attempting to create a simple scatter plot with error bars derived from the standard deviation of my data set. However, there are a few sets of data that have only a single point - and therefore the sd function returns nan.

This becomes a problem when I attempt to use the data in ggplot2, where I get the following error:

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

Here is my code that creates the average and standard deviation data:

```
avg_rxn <- rxn_data %>%
  group_by(system, solvent_type, solvent_position) %>%
  summarize(distance_mean = mean(distance),
            distance_error = sd(distance),
            energy_mean = mean(energy_rxn),
            energy_error = sd(energy_rxn))
```

And here is my code to generate the plot:

```
water_distance <- avg_rxn %>%
  filter((system == "9h0m") | (system == "8h1m")) %>%
  filter(solvent_type == "water") %>%
  #filter(solvent_position == "axial") %>%
  select(energy_mean, energy_error, system, solvent_position, distance_mean, distance_error)

ylimits = aes(ymax = energy_mean + energy_error, ymin = energy_mean - energy_error)
xlimits = aes(xmax = distance_mean + distance_error, xmin = distance_mean - distance_error)

water_distance_plot <- ggplot(data = water_distance, aes(solvent_position, x = distance_mean, 
                                                         y = energy_mean, shape = solvent_position,
                                                         color = system)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_errorbar(ylimits, xlimits, width = 0.25) +
  theme_few()

ggsave("figures/water_distance_plot.png", water_distance_plot)
```

I can imagine a couple of different solutions to this problem, but can't figure out how to implement them. The nan values could be replaced with 0 when computing avg_rxn, or ggplot2 could simply ignore the nan values during the arithmetic that computes the error bar limits.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*** edit ***

As requested, here is some of the data (including both points that work and points that do not). The spaces should allow it to be interpreted and then saved as a csv.

> ID    system  geometry_number solvent_number  solvent_position    solvent_type energy_rxn
>   0h9m_1_1  0h9m    1   1   equitorial  methanol    38.91447
>   0h9m_1_2  0h9m    1   2   equitorial  methanol    42.31569
>   0h9m_1_3  0h9m    1   3   equitorial  methanol    43.06978
>   0h9m_1_4  0h9m    1   4   axial   methanol    42.94058
>   0h9m_1_5  0h9m    1   5   axial   methanol    40.79774
>   0h9m_1_6  0h9m    1   6   axial   methanol    43.06764
>   0h9m_1_7  0h9m    1   7   axial   methanol    43.45027
>   0h9m_1_8  0h9m    1   8   axial   methanol    42.60882
>   0h9m_1_9  0h9m    1   9   axial   methanol    45.0522
>   1h8m_1_1  1h8m    1   1   equitorial  methanol    41.40231
>   1h8m_1_2  1h8m    1   2   equitorial  methanol    43.22337
>   1h8m_1_3  1h8m    1   3   equitorial  methanol    41.43154
>   1h8m_1_4  1h8m    1   4   axial   methanol    42.53526
>   1h8m_1_5  1h8m    1   5   axial   methanol    43.18862
>   1h8m_1_6  1h8m    1   6   axial   methanol    43.07718
>   1h8m_1_7  1h8m    1   7   axial   methanol    43.00857
>   1h8m_1_8  1h8m    1   8   axial   methanol    43.57557
>   1h8m_1_9  1h8m    1   9   axial   water   34.68406
>   1h8m_2_1  1h8m    2   1   equitorial  methanol    43.83503
>   1h8m_2_2  1h8m    2   2   equitorial  methanol    45.12783
>   1h8m_2_3  1h8m    2   3   equitorial  water   30.27222
>   1h8m_2_4  1h8m    2   4   axial   methanol    40.47726
>   1h8m_2_5  1h8m    2   5   axial   methanol    43.58034
>   1h8m_2_6  1h8m    2   6   axial   methanol    44.02348
>   1h8m_2_7  1h8m    2   7   axial   methanol    42.43128
>   1h8m_2_8  1h8m    2   8   axial   methanol    46.02447
>   1h8m_2_9  1h8m    2   9   axial   methanol    43.73061
>   2h7m_1_1  2h7m    1   1   equitorial  methanol    42.28647
>   2h7m_1_2  2h7m    1   2   equitorial  methanol    42.93061
>   2h7m_1_3  2h7m    1   3   equitorial  methanol    42.0748
>   2h7m_1_4  2h7m    1   4   axial   methanol    43.55864
>   2h7m_1_5  2h7m    1   5   axial   methanol    43.33525
>   2h7m_1_6  2h7m    1   6   axial   methanol    44.1656
>   2h7m_1_7  2h7m    1   7   axial   methanol    42.83685
>   2h7m_1_8  2h7m    1   8   axial   water   34.04387
>   2h7m_1_9  2h7m    1   9   axial   water   35.07239
>   2h7m_2_1  2h7m    2   1   equitorial  methanol    41.44339
>   2h7m_2_2  2h7m    2   2   equitorial  methanol    43.847
>   2h7m_2_3  2h7m    2   3   equitorial  methanol    41.59372
>   2h7m_2_4  2h7m    2   4   axial   methanol    43.49975
>   2h7m_2_5  2h7m    2   5   axial   methanol    44.02411
>   2h7m_2_6  2h7m    2   6   axial   water   34.06499
>   2h7m_2_7  2h7m    2   7   axial   methanol    44.79557
>   2h7m_2_8  2h7m    2   8   axial   methanol    44.85728
>   2h7m_2_9  2h7m    2   9   axial   water   34.51222
>   2h7m_3_1  2h7m    3   1   equitorial  methanol    41.67581
>   2h7m_3_2  2h7m    3   2   equitorial  methanol    42.25084
>   2h7m_3_3  2h7m    3   3   equitorial  methanol    42.94723
>   2h7m_3_4  2h7m    3   4   axial   methanol    43.55839
>   2h7m_3_5  2h7m    3   5   axial   methanol    43.29994
>   2h7m_3_6  2h7m    3   6   axial   water   34.7908
>   2h7m_3_7  2h7m    3   7   axial   methanol    44.08162
>   2h7m_3_8  2h7m    3   8   axial   water   35.26678
>   2h7m_3_9  2h7m    3   9   axial   methanol    44.01194
>   2h7m_4_1  2h7m    4   1   equitorial  methanol    42.30547
>   2h7m_4_2  2h7m    4   2   equitorial  methanol    43.21565
>   2h7m_4_3  2h7m    4   3   equitorial  water   33.13139
>   2h7m_4_4  2h7m    4   4   axial   methanol    44.7819
>   2h7m_4_5  2h7m    4   5   axial   methanol    44.36447
>   2h7m_4_6  2h7m    4   6   axial   methanol    42.84187
>   2h7m_4_7  2h7m    4   7   axial   methanol    43.7597
>   2h7m_4_8  2h7m    4   8   axial   methanol    42.16279
>   2h7m_4_9  2h7m    4   9   axial   water   33.87122
>   2h7m_5_1  2h7m    5   1   equitorial  methanol    43.05943
>   2h7m_5_2  2h7m    5   2   equitorial  methanol    42.42544
>   2h7m_5_3  2h7m    5   3   equitorial  water   32.6147
>   2h7m_5_4  2h7m    5   4   axial   methanol    43.9089
>   2h7m_5_5  2h7m    5   5   axial   methanol    43.74754
>   2h7m_5_6  2h7m    5   6   axial   methanol    44.32521
>   2h7m_5_7  2h7m    5   7   axial   water   34.46159
>   2h7m_5_8  2h7m    5   8   axial   methanol    44.44951
>   2h7m_5_9  2h7m    5   9   axial   methanol    44.39225
>   2h7m_6_1  2h7m    6   1   equitorial  methanol    42.45906
>   2h7m_6_2  2h7m    6   2   equitorial  water   33.08564
>   2h7m_6_3  2h7m    6   3   equitorial  water   32.82477
>   2h7m_6_4  2h7m    6   4   axial   methanol    43.5979
>   2h7m_6_5  2h7m    6   5   axial   methanol    43.62907
>   2h7m_6_6  2h7m    6   6   axial   methanol    43.77689
>   2h7m_6_7  2h7m    6   7   axial   methanol    43.35983
>   2h7m_6_8  2h7m    6   8   axial   methanol    44.43013
>   2h7m_6_9  2h7m    6   9   axial   methanol    44.49385
>   3h6m_1_1  3h6m    1   1   equitorial  methanol    44.74621
>   3h6m_1_2  3h6m    1   2   equitorial  methanol    44.08081
>   3h6m_1_3  3h6m    1   3   equitorial  methanol    41.49557
>   3h6m_1_4  3h6m    1   4   axial   methanol    42.18926
>   3h6m_1_5  3h6m    1   5   axial   methanol    44.80554
>   3h6m_1_6  3h6m    1   6   axial   methanol    46.12343
>   3h6m_1_7  3h6m    1   7   axial   water   32.94014
>   3h6m_1_8  3h6m    1   8   axial   water   35.29087
>   3h6m_1_9  3h6m    1   9   axial   water   35.75008

Comment: Could you add some (may be fake) data to tinker with?

Comment: I am sure there is a better way, but maybe you could sort your dataset and see which one is single and duplicate that value. You would have two of each.